# Heat diffusion on a 2d plate- Python

Tags: python

I need to complete a task, and I'm kind of in the middle of nowhere. I dont know whats wrong with the solver, and I dont know how to visualize the data.
My task is to simulate heat diffusion on a 2D plate. It has to have 2 heaters, and two holes in the middle of the plate. BCs are as always zero.

My questions are: 
How do I make simulation run through time? I'm asking this because when I plot it this way it shows me heaters on a plate, but all of the heat is concentrated on them. Another question is, how can I visualize the results as video or as pictures at given time? 
Here is my code. Thank you.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dt=0.1
dx=0.1

L=50                        #length of the plate
Ly=np.linspace(0,L,50)
B=50                        #width of the plate
Bx=np.linspace(0,B,50)

M=np.zeros([L,B])           #matrix

#heating device shaped like X
Gr=np.eye(10)*2000
for iGr in range(10):
    Gr[iGr,-iGr-1]=2000

#implementing heaters to matrix    
M[20:30,10:20]=Gr
M[20:30,30:40]=Gr

t=0
#wannabe solver
while t<10:
    t=0.1+t
    for j in range(1,L-1):
        for i in range(1,B-1):            
            if 24<j<28:
                if 29<i<32:
                    k=0
                elif 23<i<20: # holes for liquid
                    k=0
                else:
                    break
            else:
                k=0.5
                break

            M[i,j]=M[i,j]+k*((dt)/dx**2)*(M[i,j+1]-2*M[i,j]+M[i,j-1])+k*((dt)/dx**2)*(M[i+1,j]-2*M[i,j]+M[i-1,j])


plt.pcolormesh(M)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you like to have someone help you, ask a specific question. Debugging someone else's code code is not something many people enjoy. You might be interested in FEniCS, they solve the 2D diffusion problem in their tutorial: http://fenicsproject.org/documentation/tutorial/timedep.html#a-diffusion-problem-and-its-discretization

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might get you started.  I'm not familiar with your heat transfer function (or heat transfer functions in general) so I used a different one for these purposes.

The following code computes M for each step `dt`, and appends it to a list `MM`.

We then use `FuncAnimation` to step through the elements of `MM` (recall that the elements of `MM` are the snapshots of matrix `M`) and display them.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

dt=0.1
dx=0.1

L=50                        # length of the plate
B=50                        # width of the plate


#heating device shaped like X
Gr=np.eye(10)*2000
for iGr in range(10):
    Gr[iGr,-iGr-1]=2000

# Function to set M values corresponding to non-zero Gr values
def assert_heaters(M, Gr):
    M[20:30,10:20] = np.where(Gr > 0, Gr, M[20:30,10:20])
    M[20:30,30:40] = np.where(Gr > 0, Gr, M[20:30,30:40])


M=np.zeros([L,B])           # matrix
assert_heaters(M, Gr)

# Build MM, a list of matrices, each element corresponding to M at a given step
T = np.arange(0,10,dt)
MM = []
for itime in xrange(len(T)):
    for j in range(1,L-1):
        for i in range(1,B-1):
            k=0.5  # default k
            if 24<j<28:
                # holes for liquid
                if 29<i<32 or 23<i<20: k=0

            #dm = k * ((dt)/dx**2) * (M[i,j+1] + M[i,j-1] - 2*M[i,j]) + \
            #     k * ((dt)/dx**2) * (M[i+1,j] + M[i-1,j] - 2*M[i,j])
            #M[i,j] += dm
            M[i,j] = (M[i-1,j] + M[i+1,j] + M[i,j-1] + M[i,j+1])/4

    # Re-assert heaters
    assert_heaters(M, Gr)

    MM.append(M.copy())



fig = plt.figure()
pcm = plt.pcolormesh(MM[0])
plt.colorbar()

# Function called to update the graphic
def step(i):
    if i >= len(MM): return
    pcm.set_array(MM[i].ravel())
    plt.draw()

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, step, interval=50)
plt.show()
```

You'll have to correct the transfer function to your own of course.

This code produces something like [this animation](https://i.imgur.com/H05eNqW.gif)  (Note, it's 3M, too big to embed in the answer)

Compressed version:

[image]

Comment: @cvut, if it helped, please consider upvoting / marking as answer -- if you end up solving your problem yourself, feel free to come back and answer your own question -- then upvoting and selecting your own answer as correct :)